# How to set different "limit" parameters for feed and likes in Android Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to implement a method in Android by using Facebook SDK to make a GraphRequest to have the feed of the currently logged in user.

```
public void getMyStatusInformation(AccessToken accessToken){
    GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(
            accessToken,
            "/me/feed",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    JSONObject responseObject =  response.getJSONObject();
                    try {
                        onStatusesReceived(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "likes,story");
    parameters.putString("limit", "2");
    graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
}
```

I want to get only last 2 posts of the user, but get all the likes of his/her friends to those posts. However, when I execute this GraphRequest, the response contains 2 posts with maximum number of 2 likes.

I tried /me/feed?limit=2, had address not found error.
Tried 
parameters.putString("fields", "likes,story.limit(2)"); had the error "Story parameter does not support subfield limit"

Changed the order as:

```
parameters.putString("limit", "2");
parameters.putString("fields", "likes,story");
```

But nothing changed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you able to keep the limit param but provide a higher limit specifically for the likes edge? e.g. `likes.limit(50)`?